# Tricky parametrization problem

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find $|r(1)|$ if $|r(0)| = 0$ and $(r \text{dot} r')(t) = 6t^2$ $\forall t$.

What is the trick for this one? How do I work backwards?

Comment: what is the "dot"? is it the function composition symbol?

Comment: Don't you have $|r|^2=r.r$ ? Derive this expression on $t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac12\|\vec{r}\|^2\right)=\frac12\frac{d}{dt}\left(\vec{r}\cdot\vec{r}\right)=\vec{r}\cdot\dot{\vec{r}}$$

So if $\vec{r}\cdot\dot{\vec{r}}=6t^2$, we can integrate to find:

$$\frac12\|\vec{r}(1)\|^2-\frac12\|\vec{r}(0)\|^2=\int_0^16t^2\,dt\\
\implies \frac12\|\vec{r}(1)\|^2=2\\
\implies \|\vec{r}(1)\|=2.$$

Comment: Very clear, thank you!